# Laravel relationships belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I want to fetch all orders and connect them with their statuses, but I want only the last status for each. I was trying to do it like this, but I only get the status for the first order the rest doesn't have any. How can I fix it?

```
static function actualKioskOrders()
{
    $orders = Order::query();

    return $orders->with([
        'statuses' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        }
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order model add this method, I suggest doing query on model class.

```
public function status(){
return $this-> belongsToMany(Status::class);
}

public function latestStatus() 

   return $this->status()->latest()->first();
}
```

.

Comment: I want to have all orders with their only last status... and my relation i belongsToMAny

Comment: thats how u get that, didnt see that correctly. edited

Comment: ok but when i write in controller like this :  $orders = Order::actualKioskOrders()->get(); - now I have all orders with all statauses, but I want to have all orders with each with last status

Comment: In foreach in view?

Comment: just call thw mwthod Order::latestStatus();

Comment: My laravel doesn't see method last() :(

Comment: which laravel version; tey latest() instead

Comment: public function latestStatus() {     return $this->status()->latest()->first()

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easier way to do it would be

```
$orders = Order::with('status')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```

Then if you `dd($orders);` you will have all the orders with their corresponded status.